# boost::describe: How do I get the unadorned enum's name?

Tags: c++, boost, enums

Boost *describe* [lets you describe](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#ref_boostdescribeenum_hpp) enums and [inspect](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#example_printing_enums_ct) those descriptions. I see how to get an enum's members, but is there a way to get the name of the enumeration itself?

```
class Outer {

...

enum class MyEnum {
    FirstItem = 88,
    SecondItem = 99,
    };

...

BOOST_DESCRIBE_NESTED_ENUM(MyEnum, FirstItem, SecondItem)
}; // Outer
```

I'd like to get the unadorned enumeration name "MyEnum" from boost::describe, since `typeid(MyEnum).name` returns the mangled *snigglefritzMyEnumSnigglefritz*.

Same for the non-nested version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think describe stores the name of the type described (surprisingly?). The same goes for classes and unions, judging [from the examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#examples).

Instead you can use Boost Core:

```
std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(Outer::MyEnum).name()) << "\n";
```

Or Boost TypeIndex:

```
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id<Outer::MyEnum>().pretty_name() << "\n";
```

E.g.

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/079a1846a102f18f)**

```cpp
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <boost/describe.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Outer {
    enum class MyEnum {
        FirstItem  = 88,
        SecondItem = 99,
    };

    BOOST_DESCRIBE_NESTED_ENUM(MyEnum, FirstItem, SecondItem)
}; // Outer

constexpr auto unqualified(std::string_view sv) { return sv.substr(sv.find_last_of(":") + 1); }

int main() {
    auto core = boost::core::demangle(typeid(Outer::MyEnum).name());
    auto tidx = boost::typeindex::type_id<Outer::MyEnum>().pretty_name();
    std::cout << core << "\n";
    std::cout << tidx << "\n";
    std::cout << unqualified(core) << "\n";
    std::cout << unqualified(tidx) << "\n";

    for (auto e : {Outer::MyEnum::FirstItem, Outer::MyEnum::SecondItem})
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(e) << " -> " << boost::describe::enum_to_string(e, "unknown") << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
Outer::MyEnum
Outer::MyEnum
MyEnum
MyEnum
88 -> FirstItem
99 -> SecondItem
```

Comment: Thanks for these options! Looking at the heavily-templated [example code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/describe/doc/html/describe.html#example_printing_enums_ct) (`... mp_for_each ... describe_enumerators ...`) it's reasonable to put that all into a macro (`#define`) in which case you're passing in the type name and can make it a string with `#T` with the preprocessor. In the spirit of the `BOOST_DESCRIBE_...` macros.